# How do I group nodes by a different node property and order by a different one in Neo4j?

Tags: sql, neo4j, dataset, cypher, aggregate-functions

I am working with [crimes in Boston](https://www.kaggle.com/ankkur13/boston-crime-data?select=crime.csv) dataset, with each crime as nodes in Neo4j. I want to query and display the most committed crimes each year to get a result like this:

| Year | offense_code_group | count(offense_code_group) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2015 | Aggravated Assault | 5827 |
| 2016 | Larceny From Motor Vehicle | 11534 |
| 2017 | Verbal Disputes | 12049 |
| 2018 | Investigate Person | 8724 |

*Note: The result is just an example of how I want it to group and look, not the actual result I'll get after querying the dataset.*

But this is the best I have been able to do so far:
[query and output in neo4j desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MeqmS.png)

I know there is no GROUP BY clause in Neo4j and I have tried using collect(), but I can't get it to work.

Comment: So what is missing? Seems like your query already does the job

Comment: It's partially working -- it just happens to be displayed in the order of year because of count(offense_code_group). But if you see the output, 2017 occurs 3-4times since it's just displaying the crime, its number of occurrences, and the year, instead of showing years alongside the offense that occurred the most in that particular year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
MATCH (c:Crime)
WITH c.year AS year, c.offense_code_group AS code, count(c.offense_code_group) AS count
ORDER BY year, count DESC
WITH year, COLLECT(code) AS codes, COLLECT(count) AS counts
RETURN year, codes[0], counts[0]
```